# Invalid argument error installing 'ruby-box' gem

Tags: ruby, box-api

Any ideas why I get this error when trying to install the ruby-box gem?

```
C:\>gem install ruby-box

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EINVAL)
    Invalid argument - C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-box-1.2.0/spec/fixtures/i☺ e?↨f§↓.jpg
```

It seems to be complaining about the `ruby-box-master\spec\fixtures\遠志教授.jpg` file, which is not written in English.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably move to the newer ruby SDK:  https://github.com/attachmentsme/ruby-box

It is all built on the V2 API.   V1 API will be shut down at the end of 2013.

Comment: That's what I was using.  The ruby-box gem has been updated now to 1.2.1 to remove the UTF-8 encoded file that was causing the problem. Still need to test it out.

Answer (score 0):

Update ruby-box to 1.2.1 (still need to test it)